# Why isn't the distance travelled recorded?

Tags: zombies-run

I have [Zombies, Run!](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/zombies-run!/id503519713) on the iPhone. I ran for 36 minutes yet on the statistics it says total distance 0.00 km. Is there a way to fix it? Location (on iPhone settings) is on, and I'm assuming there is no need to have internet data for GPS to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check that location had actually locked on before you started running? If a location lock is not obtained this can happen. Depending on where you are running getting a lock can be hard (e.g. in a city with many tall buildings).

Data is not required for GPS, but can increase the speed with which you can get a lock (by downloading constellation information from the internet instead of waiting for it from the satellites themselves).

If you are sure that you have a location lock and that your route has been recorded correctly, try re-syncing the data. I know that Runkeeper often requires syncing after finishing a run, maybe Run, Zombies! is the same.